# At a low price point, should I buy one more upmarket trekking pole, or two lower quality ones?

Tags: gear, ultralight, trekking-poles

I have never used trekking poles on grounds of being an additional expense, making you stand out from casual walkers, leaving you no free hands, and not being suitable for aircraft hand luggage (I travel with a 36-litre rucksack in order to fly more cheaply). Instead I would tend to take a walking stick from the forest and put it back at the end of the walk.

However I am currently planning on a trip in the Balkans, Turkey and the Caucasus where I want one or two trekking poles partly to help me deter feral dogs, and partly for my trekking pole tent, a Lanshan 1 or Lanshan 2 (I have yet to buy - the tent will used mainly in cases when I don’t reach the next hostel by nightfall). The Lanshan 2 would require me to purchase two trekking poles, whereas the Lanshan 1 would require me to buy just one. For me there is nothing separating the two tents, other than the number of trekking poles I will have.

I will budget $30 for buying trekking poles once I arrive in the Balkans, which need to hold up under normal usage without snapping. What would be better on balance at this low price point, a single more upmarket trekking pole, or a pair of lower quality?

Comment: Cheaper doesn't necessarily mean less durable. It's more likely to mean heavier and lacking in features like shock absorbers

Comment: Chris H just to let you know I just edited "less durable" to "lower quality"

Comment: having a trekking pole just so that you can pitch your tent is not the best calculation: a pair of poles will be at least 5-600g, when a single 120cm pole from a reasonably light aluminium will be around 50-100g. I also wouldn't necessarily find poles more efficient than a regular stick against feral dogs.

Comment: @njzk2 The calculation I have done is that a trekking pole(s) will be lighter than a natural walking stick plus tent poles, and that a trekking pole tent plus $30 worth of trekking poles will not be more expensive than a comparable normal tent including $30 worth of tent poles. Also, I want some kind of stick to deter dogs in urban/suburban areas, where there might be no natural sticks lying around. (I don't need to hit the dogs, just raise the pole(s) above my head to make myself look big.)

Comment: When you are flying, I would opt for foldable poles and if weight is more of a concern than durability, I would opt for carbon instead of alu. However, foldable carbon poles are definitely above the 30$ range

Comment: a pole in 3*40cm sections (worth 15$ at a specialized store) fits your carry-on (e.g.: https://www.extremtextil.de/en/tent-poles.html)

Comment: @njzk Suitability for hand luggage is defo an advantage of tent poles vs trekking poles I've been thinking about. However I don't need to buy until after my flight, & one of the cheapest options for return will be Kutaisi (lax security in my experience)>Budapest (trekking poles pass security according to outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4374/trekking-poles-on-planes)>UK. Also the Lanshan trekking pole tents have decent build quality, low price+weight, ample internal space, availability in the UK, and layout allows you to enjoy the view from a position sitting in the middle of the tent.

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks for the link by the way, it will come in handy should I decide in the end to go with tent poles over trekking poles!

Answer (score 2):

My personal opinion back when I was a lot younger would have been  to get the upmarket one. The whole "you get what you pay for" ball of wax, but that was when most products were made for quality instead of quantity. Nowadays though that's a different ballgame. Back in the early to mid 90's I swore by Oakley sunglasses. I wasn't impressed by the iridium from outer space spiel. The quality of the lenses and the craftsmanship that went into the production and design were what impressed me. Also their warranty basically no questions asked was a winner winner chicken dinner to me. They were pricey sure, but to me it was worth it. Now I probably wouldn't own a pair of Oakley's if they paid me to (lies, I totally would if they paid me. I'm not an idiot lol)

I would do the two so called  "lower quality" trekking poles. Two is better than one. And if you just utilize one at a time for fending off those mean ol hound dogs and whatnot and it gets damaged in the fracas well then you have yourself a spare.

Hope that my rambling answer helps you in the end. As for your budget, have you done any online "window shopping" looking for discounted, slightly used poles? Perhaps you could get 2 of the more upmarket poles, if they are of higher quality and of more durable construction (I'm not really "in the know" so to speak on the different brands and materials used for trekking poles) and still maybe have a bit more pocket money for socializing with any locals you might encounter.

Answer (score 1):

I have both an expensive set and economy set of poles. Strangely enough, the higher priced set has had the most issues (guards popping off, etc) although they are lighter in weight. If choosing one expensive vs two cheaper, I would go cheaper and get two. Also, having two helps balance out your stride with tramping/hiking.